# Modifying drawing of .net MAUI controls

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, winui-3

Is there any way for me to modify how a UI Control Element is draw?
I am working on an app currently only for windows desktops where I am using the Switch Control from MAUI. However the switches are drawn with a textbox to the side and no way of modifying the border color of the switch or removing the text on the side as seen here:

[image].

The currently implementation of Switches only allow for changing of the background and the dot colors. I cant seem to wrap my head around what is drawing the entire switch object and where I would need to modify it to make the switch stand out more on a darker background.

Comment: the docs cover how to customize a control using a Handler.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize

Comment: Have a look at [control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate)